VSCode dev containers: PATH value in initializeCommand phase
I would like to know how to set the path that the command initializeCommand is using. So, for example if I have this command as specified in the devcontainers.json
"initializeCommand": { "my-command": "do-my-command.cmd" },
and I have such structure:

(repo root)/etc/do-my-command.cmd
(repo root)/VsCode/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
(repo root)/VsCode/.devcontainer/Dockerfile

How can I tell VSCode that my script is inside /etc (and this, outside the VsCode)? I am running docker in windows
It appears that VSCode figures out the directory by itself, but it seems weird for me. So the question would be how to specified the PATH for the command, and how to make this path relative.
